# When using MessageListenerContainer, MDC not propagate on receiving message

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

We can receive messages by configuring a `MessageListenerContainer` and providing a message listener or by using the `@KafkaListener` annotation.

When I use `@KafkaListener`, if a message comes, `traceId` goes to `MDC` automatically. this scenario is Ok. But when I use `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`, `traceId` not recognized from the received message, so the application creates new `traceId`!

My Code:

**Scenario 1: ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer**

```
 @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConsumerFactory consumerFactory) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = getContainerProperties();
        containerProperties.setMessageListener((MessageListener<String, MyMessage>) this::getMessage);
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(consumerFactory, containerProperties);

        return messageListenerContainer;
    }
```

****Scenario 2: @KafkaListener****

```
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "some_topic",
            groupId = "some_group",
            containerFactory = "ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void getMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage> record){
      //doSth
    }
```

Comment: I think this is just because Spring Cloud Sleuth does an instrumentation around a `@KafkaLisntener` infrastructure, but does nothing for a plain direct `setMessageListener()` configuration.